# Join extruded vertex with edge

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

I need to join a vertex to edge, with *snap to edge* i can snap my vertex on the edge but i don't know how to join it.

Now my solution is:

1. snap vertex to edge
2. subdivide edge (this creates a new vertex on the edge)
3. merge the two vertices

But i think is too elaborate, so i look for a simpler solution.

[image]

Comment: Performing this like is shown on the screenshot will cause Ngons / tris / other bad geometry types which are better to avoid or to fix later. In order to join one vertex to edge there should be vertex on that edge already. So yes, Snap Utilities Line will work for this case but like any other method in this case will produce topology which is better to fix later

Comment: It's not elaborate, you'll see.  {RMB{g{ctrl}{LMB}a{RMB}{shift}{RMB}2ws{shift}{LMB}{alt}M2.  It took me more keystrokes to write "elaborate."  As you get better, these kinds of actions will come easier and easier.  But don't do this.  It's not just ngons, it's worse, it's discontiguous normals.

Answer (score 1):

Subdivide is a bad option in your situation because you get more verticals than you need.

The fastest way, in my opinion, is to manage this with a loop cut.

1. Loop Cut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and slide to the position where you want to connect your vertex
2. Select your vertices and merge <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> them

[image]

You could the same with the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd>). However you can't guarantee  for a good mesh flow if you do so. 
With Loop Cuts you are most of the time on the good side.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question maybe a quick solution.

Download the [addon Snap utilities](https://github.com/Mano-Wii/Addon-Snap-Utilities-Line/blob/master/mesh_snap_utilities_line.py)

Press <kbd>T</kbd> in toolshelf -> Snap utilities ->

Select the single verts and click on the line from the addon and draw the line from verts to edge. You will get a edge and a new verts.

To confirm the operation press <kbd>Enter</kbd> To Exit <kbd>Esc</kbd>

[image]